# Change google open id log in mail address for stack overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid, user-accounts, login

- Initially i started to use stack overflow using rachel.s@neonous.com with account name rachel and i have 129 reputation.
- Now i need to log in into same account using some other id. for eg: rachel@abc.com
- The issue is, both the above id's are maintained by Google. so when i log in using rachel@abc.com, its creating new account.
- I want to log in to account name rachel with rachel@abc.com.
- My rachel.s@neonous.com account is going to expire in two days, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all login with the *old* email id. Then go to your profile -> click on `my logins` -> click on `add more logins…`. Now select *log in with Google* option and here you need to log in with your *new* email id. Done. Now if you login with the new email id, it will login into your main(old) Stack Overflow account.

Comment: yes its done... thanks a lot..